# Cant edit messages with discord bot (UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Ive got my bot running with some new code but it cant edit any messages using `message.edit()` throws a `DiscordAPIError` Any help would be appreciated.

Heres my code for my super simple bot

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
 });

client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content === 'lenny') {
 message.edit('( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)');
 }
 });

client.login('Censored to protect identity');
```

This is the console output whenever someone says 'lenny' in a text channel.

```
(node:6672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user
    at C:\Users\Terra Byte\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15
    at C:\Users\Terra Byte\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
(node:6672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
```

I have tried giving the role administrator on the server, but it still throws the same `DiscordAPIError` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that error is being thrown is because your trying to edit **another** users message.

```
client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content === 'lenny') {
 message.edit('( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)'); // <-- Here you are editing another users message.
 }
 });
```

The message you are trying to edit belongs to the person who authored the message, and you cannot edit other users messages. 
As you stated above, you wanted it to delete the message, so I'll implement that below.

```
client.on('message', message => {
 if (message.content === 'lenny') {
 message.delete() //This is the original message that triggered the message event.
 message.channel.send("( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)") //Send a lenny face in response to the user saying "lenny"
 }
 });
```

You don't need to search for it, just use the definition of message in your **message** event.

Comment: This ended up to be what i did after all but i beat you to it. Answered tick for best answer

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative option to what you're asking for but can't do, you can have the bot post a new message when someone posts "!lenny", through `message.channel.send()`. Or you can make it even easier and create a custom Emoji for your server that shows a lenny face in the place of :lenny:, something like this: https://discordemoji.com/emoji/Lenny

[image]

Comment: Ended up searching for the message, deleting it and having the bot send the lennyface, kinda what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Messages from other users can not be edited in discord at all, even/especially using the API.

Comment: Really! Ill have to rethink my program then!